# Names for two different kinds of first-order graph properties

Tags: logic, terminology, model-theory

Let's define a simple graph as a model of $\{ \forall x (\lnot xRx), \forall x y (xRy \to yRx) \}$.

Consider the property of a graph $G$ being bipartite.

This property can be encoded with a first-order theory in the language of graphs but NOT with a first-order sentence in the language of graphs.

My question is twofold:

- Which notion of a first-order property does "first-order property" usually refer to?
- How do you distinguish properties that can be encoded with a sentence from ones that can be encoded with a theory?

---

**What follows is a proof of the claim I'm making to support my question.**

---

A graph is bipartite if and only if it does not contain any odd cycles.

As proof, pick a vertex in each connected component arbitrarily and begin coloring the graph greedily, alternating colors each time. This process succeeds if and only if there are no odd cycles. And the presence of an odd cycle would defeat any attempt to 2-color the graph.

This can be expressed with a *first-order theory* (**called** $T$) in the language $(R)$:

- $R$ is a simple graph.
- for all odd $n$, $\lnot \exists x_1 \cdots x_n ( \text{$x_1 \cdots x_n$ are all distinct and form a cycle of length $n$} )$

However, it cannot be expressed with a first-order $(R)$-sentence.

Proof:

- Suppose the sentence $\lnot \varphi$ held if and only if $R$ was bipartite.
- Thus $\varphi$ holds if and only if $R$ is not bipartite.
- Consider the theory $T \cup \{\varphi\}$. I will show that it is finitely satisfiable.

  - Any finite subset $\Delta_0$ of $T \cup \{\varphi\}$ contains only finitely many sentences prohibiting odd cycles. Let $k$ be the smallest odd number such that a cycle of length $k$ is not prohibited by $\Delta_0$. Let the graph $G$ consist exactly of a cycle of length $k$. $G$ is not $2$-colorable, so it follows that $G \models \Delta_0$. $G$ is also a simple graph and so it satisfies the first pair of conditions in $T$ as well.
- Since $T \cup \{\varphi\}$ is finitely satisfiable, there exists a model $M$ such that $M \models T, \varphi$.
- However, $T$ is equivalent to $\lnot \varphi$, thus $M \models \varphi, \lnot \varphi$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: A good question about the terminology of model theory (I can't answer it, not my subject) but it has nothing to do with graph theory. You might as well have used as your example plain sets with the property of being infinite.

Comment: Many long years ago I was hanging out with some logic students who spoke oif "elementary classes (in the narrow sense)" and "elementary classes in the wider sense", abbreviated EC and EC$_\Delta$, the former being characterized by a single sentence, the latter by a set of sentences. I think this terminology originated with Tarski. But that was a long time ago; I've no idea what they are called now.

Comment: @bof [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class), in model theory these are called `basic elementary classes` for the sentence variant and `elementary classes` for the theory variant. Except that finite model theory uses the older terminology you used in your second comment. I think fields outside model theory frequently talk about `first-order properties` but seldom talk about `elementary classes`, so I am curious what people mean by `first-order` in different areas.

Comment: Graph properties are also kind of neat because there are at least two logics that you can reasonably use to talk about them: first-order logic in the language $R$, and [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic).

Comment: Whatever terminology you decide to go with in your writing, be sure to include a definition and not assume your reader will understand the term the same way you do. Mathematics is timeless; people may be reading your work 100 years from now, and the terminology will have changed again by then.